# TrainImageContentDetector example aborts on GPU

Tags: bugs, neural-networks, linux, gpu

I'm running v13.2.1 on Ubuntu and trying to run the built-in examples. But I see a "GPU memory exhausted" error on the first one in the docs for `TrainImageContentDetector`:

[image]

However, I have 16gb of gpu memory and it's only using ~5gb:

[image]

**Update:**

I tried setting a lower `BatchSize`, it's red so can't tell it's a hidden option and it seems to not respect it:

[image]

Comment: My *NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti * cannot do it either

Comment: Seems like a bug or what?